# How do I $concat fields in an array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

## What I have

I have the following documents coming into my aggregation pipeline:

```
[
    { 
        "email" : "email@example.com", 
        "name"  : "Organization Name",  
        "users" : [
            {
                "lastName"  : "Nye", 
                "firstName" : "Bill", 
                "email"     : "bnye@example.com"
            },
            {
                "lastName"  : "Rogers", 
                "firstName" : "Mr.", 
                "email"     : "mrrogers@example.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

## What I want

Using`$project` I want to `$concat` the `firstName` and `lastName` fields within each of the array subdocuments to get the following result:

```
{ 
    "email" : "email@example.com", 
    "name"  : "Organization Name",  
    "users" : [
        {
            "name"  : "Bill Nye", 
            "email" : "bnye@example.com"
        },
        {
            "name"  : "Mr. Rogers", 
            "email" : "mrrogers@example.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

## What I've tried - Attempt #1

I've tried the following aggregation:

```
db.organizations.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            email : 1,
            name  : 1,
            users : {
              name  : { $concat : [ "$users.firstName", " ", "$users.lastName" ] },
              email : 1
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

... but I get the following error:

> $concat only supports strings, not Array

## What I've tried - Attempt #2

I've also tried the following aggregation:

```
db.organizations.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            email : 1,
            name  : 1,
            users : {
              name  : { $concat : [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] },
              email : 1
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

... but `name` always returns `null`.

I feel as if this should be a relatively simple thing to do, however, I'm completely stumped.

**How do I get the results that I'm looking for?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply do this by [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat)ing your documents and use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) aggregation variable operator to apply the [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat) expression to each item in an array and returns an array with the applied results.

```
db.organizations.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "email": 1, 
            "name": 1, 
            "users": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$users", 
                    "as": "u", 
                      "in": { 
                          "name": { "$concat" : [ "$$u.firstName", " ", "$$u.lastName" ] }, 
                          "email": "$$u.email" 
                      } 
                }
            } 
        }} 
    ]
)
```

Comment: While this answer works just as well as @chridam's answer and tackles the problem from a different angle, I ended up using his solution. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @docksteaderluke I knew you will use this solution;) because despite the fact that the other answer is  "factually correct",  it's definitely not the way to go.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Why is it not the way to go?

Comment: @docksteaderluke The first problem is the length of the pipeline. The second is the presence of the `$unwind`  in the pipeline. `$unwind` is very costly in terms of performance because it produces a Cartesian product of each  document and the array field in the document. This results in a lot more documents to process down in the pipeline.

Comment: While that is true, `unwind` can be very fast if it only touches indexed elements, which makes it mem-only. At least this is so documented in Mongo's own reference. But I certainly agree that for the given issue, `unwind` is overkill.